# Не выходит создать приложение Windows Forms в MVS 2017

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++

На картинке, для добавления которой мне не хватает каких-то очков репутации, видно, что создать такой тип приложения можно, поскольку присутствует соответствующая строка в разделе Visual C++/ Среда CLR, однако при нажатии "ок" ничего кроме появления надписи "не удалось создать проект" не происходит.

Если следовать всевозможным витающим в интернетах инструкциям для более ранних версий Visual Studio (2012, 2013), то при исполнении действия "После создания проекта нажать на вкладку Проект->Добавить новый элемент->UI->форма Windows Form" вылезает вот такая ошибка. Как быть?
[image: Рис.3.]

Comment: Какие-то компоненты не установлены.

Answer (score 0):

[Инструкцыя](https://vscode.ru/articles/windows-forms-cpp.html)

Если не компилируется до установи компонент 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Если ошыбка визуального редактора формы как у вас на скрине](http://streletzcoder.ru/lechim-vizualnyiy-redaktor-dlya-windows-forms-v-visual-c-2015/)